# Observed Deterministic in pymc3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I am trying to port a model from Infer.NET, and I am struggling with 
how can I make a Deterministic variable observed in pymc3?

M,L ~ Bernoulli

```
# doesn't work ...
Deterministic("U %i" % i, switch(M[i], ~L[i], L[i]), observed=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you are trying to model (you are more likely to get replies with a complete description of the problem and attempt at code), but in pymc3 you pass data via the 'observed' argument to specify the likelihood function. For example, if you want to estimate the probability of success for Bernoulli-distributed random variable, the likelihood for the model would be

```
likelihood = pm.Bernoulli('likelihood', prior_p_success, observed=data)
```

where `prior_p_success` is the prior probability of success and `data` is a vector of your binary data.